# can i use PuTTY to transfer files to my PC?

Tags: putty, scp, winscp

i'm having trouble connecting to our cluster with winSCP can i use PuTTY as an alternative?

How do i transfer files to my PC using PuTTY or some other alternative for winSCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes,

1. Download the `pscp.exe` file from PuTTy.org. Click the file name and save it to your computer.
   If you want a PuTTY shell program, download and install `putty.exe` as well.
2. At the Windows command prompt, enter:

   pscp source_file_name userid@server_name:/path/destination_file_name.

For example:

```
c:\>pscp june06extract wrhse@warehouse.cit.cornell.edu:/mydata/june06extract.
```

When prompted, enter your password for the server.

Comment: worked, but i needed to add pscp to my path

Comment: well add it to your path: this will help you http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Nope, please don't do that.  Encouraging people to use putty.org should not be done, and likewise I recommend people don't follow such advice. The [Latest Official PuTTY documentation's section about putty.org](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org) (e.g. [Version 0.77 of that documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org)) is not referring to that domain positively.  More commended: Download PuTTY-related software from [the proper website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).